# Analyzing the Login History

Tags: soql, api

My org uses Salesforce as a customer facing ticket system. Lately we've noticed that some customers are creating multiple accounts. We'd like to find out how many excess accounts we have.

Our Login History file can be hundreds of thousands of rows. going through our process (see below) in Excel of all things is slow and tedious. Doing the same process in a Salesforce report is even slower.

We're looking to find or build a small tool that can help us. We'll either have to use Visual Force / Apex / SOQL / SOSL code (no experience with this in the org) - or through some external code that parses the csv export (visual basic, python, and Ruby on Rails have all been brought up).

Here's our current methodology that we're looking to streamline / automate if possible:

1. Export the Login History to a CSV file.
2. Open with Excel and save as an XLSX file, pretty it up with a table.
3. Filter on a specific username. Copy their Source IPs to a list. Clear the username filter.
4. Filter by the first IP on the list, check the results for other usernames that have used the same IP. Copy down their username to notepad, and then clear the Source IP filter.
5. Repeat step 4 until the IP list has been gone through.
6. Repeat step 3 until the username list has been gone through, continue to step 4.
7. Rinse and repeat only on new data.

**Has anyone seen a pre-made script / tool that does anything similar to this, or has a suggestion on how to make this process more streamlined?**

Sidenote: Afterwards we run various Salesforce reports on the usernames for human analysis.

We are aware of the Salesforce API to access the Login History, e.g. https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_loginhistory.htm

Comment: Is this a Customer Community you're asking about? If so, when you use the term "Account" are you referring to "Community User"? Are your Users associated with Business Accounts or can they create a new User Profile and Account when they log-in as a new user? Clarifying the details of your use case would be helpful as there may be more than one way of approaching this than just IP addresses using dupe finder utilities.

Comment: @crmprogdev We do not use the community stuff at all. We solely use the Salesforce Case system as a ticket system. All users are individuals using portal logins at a asdf.force.com site. Users are using customer portal licenses.